# javascript regexp does not allow my expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm wanting to use javascript regexp to test if my string matches a regular expression.  However, the regular expression that I'm trying to use causes my javascript to break.

I understand that I can typically do the following:

```
/e/.test("blah")
```

but when I try to use my expression, my browser barfs:

```
/(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )/.test("1.23")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Javascript does not support look-behind assertions.

Comment: Why is this tagged R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript does not support [**Negative or Positive Lookbehind**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertions. Therefore, your browser should be throwing an error for Invalid regular expression: ( Invalid group ) because of the Positive Lookbehind `(?<=^| )` ...

I would start off with using beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors ..

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test("1.23")
```

And if you really want to assert the beginning of string/whitespace or end of string/whitespace positions, you could compile them using capturing groups instead of lookaround assertions since you are only using the test method.

```
/(^| ) PATTERN ($| )/
```